# How do I ignore collision between This object and the Other?

Tags: unity

I'm just starting out in Unity and I'm making this cute & janky little rocket game. I want to implement a "medallion" pickup. My code looks like this:

```
public class CollisionHandler : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {   switch(other.gameObject.tag){
            case1 "Collectable":
                AudioSource.PlayOneShot(AudioClip);
             // Physics.IgnoreCollision(other, GetComponent<Collider>(), true);
                Destroy(other.gameObject);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works up until the "Physics.IgnoreCollision" line. Specifically, Unity tells me "Error: Cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Collision' to 'UnityEngine.Collider'". At least I know that "Collisions" and "Colliders" are different objects but I still have no idea what I'm doing wrong because I don't even know how to do this right in the first place.

I want to get the "Collision" component of my rocket doohickey. When I get the medal, it disappears and the audion plays, but it's like I just flew into a floating wall! I want the player to pass through the medal as they collect it. The medal vanishes and the sfx play.

Where am I going wrong? Is there an easier way to do this? I'd love links, advice, tutorials, etc. I have no idea if anybody else has asked this question before me.

Comment: Did you consider looking at [the API documentation for the Collision type](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision.html), to find what `Collider` type members it has that you can reference? When a mechanical compiler program can tell you what's wrong with your code, it's probably not something you need to ask about here — the documentation or even Intellisense alone can explain what options you have that satisfy basic type checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the collision has occurred is too late to ignore it.

Instead, you can click the "Is Trigger" checkbox on one of the two colliders involved in the collision (or set this in code with `collider.isTrigger = true` *before* the collision occurs) to make it a kind of "ghost" collider. It will *detect* collisions with other colliders, and report `OnTriggerEnter`/`Stay`/`Exit` events, but will not alter the motion of the body it contacted or its own rigidbody in response to the collision.

For a medallion pickup, you almost certainly want the medallion's collider to be a trigger, and then pick it up inside `OnTriggerEnter()`.

If you need both objects to use non-trigger colliders (ie. they need to have solid, bouncing collisions with other things, just not with each other), you can use physics layers and collision masks to separate their non-trigger colliders so they don't interact, then add an extra trigger collider to one of them that interacts with the other.

I'd also recommend using physics layers and collision layer masks instead of tag checks when you can. It's much more efficient to simply never process the collision in the first place, because the two layers don't interact, rather than processing the collision and invoking a collision handler routine that does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to move the objects into different layers, then in the Layer collision matrix settings uncheck the layers that you want to ignore collisions between.

Here's the reference:  [Layer-based collision detection](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html)